# Access Application Menu Item with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator, menu-bar

I am trying to create a global hotkey for a function of an app by building an AppleScript in Automator.app and then assign a hotkey to it in Service. But the AppleScript doesn't work.

Specifically, I'm trying to click the *Set as system proxy* item of ClashX.app.

[image]

and the item path is showed as below:

[image]

My AppleScript (sorry IDK the corr. syntax highlight):

```js
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "ClashX" 
        tell process "ClashX"
            click menu item "Set as system proxy" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

and it comes out

```
Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found “"”.
```

Note: the process name seems to be "ClashX", but I'm newbie to OS, so I post it here FYI.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is how you'd click that target *menu item*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "ClashX"
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    click menu item "Set as system proxy" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
end tell
```

That said though, sometimes there can be a delay of several seconds, or more, between the first *click* and the second *click*. If you find that to be the case, then try the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* instead:

```applescript
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "ClashX"
    end tell
end ignoring
do shell script "killall 'System Events'"
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu item "Set as system proxy" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "ClashX"
    end tell
end ignoring
```

However, assigning a *global keyboard shortcut* for an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* can be difficult at best because finding a *keyboard shortcut* that will not step on an already assigned *keyboard shortcut* in every *application* that you could trigger the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* in will not be easy.

Additionally, every *application* you do successfully trigger the *keyboard shortcut* in will have to be added to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, and that can be such a pain. Also, you actually may not want a given *application* to have *accessibility privileges* for security reasons.

To work around the *accessibility privileges* issues in a use case such as this I avoid **Automator** and just use an **AppleScript** *script* triggered by a *keyboard shortcut* using e.g. [**FastScripts**](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), or a similar type of *application*. Using **FastScripts** I find that I typically only have to give it *accessibility privileges* and not the *application* that was *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* was triggered.

This still leaves the *global keyboard shortcut* issue though and you may end up having to use four or five *keys* and the non-modifier *key* will most likely have to be a *symbol*.

---

<sup>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of FastScripts, just a satisfied user of the product.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tested your solution but it seems not work as I thought. I’m busy this month and haven't check the reason behind yet. But I accept it as the answer because it gives me a path to solve it. I will comment the detailed feedback later!

Answer (score 1):

The `click` command cannot be performed by the application ClashX. The `click` command can be performed by System Events. Try this instead…

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "ClashX"
    click menu item "Set as system proxy" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 ¬
        of menu bar 2 of application process "ClashX"
end tell
```

Answer (score -3):

Using MTMR (touch bar custom tool)

Comment: It's helpful when answers go into more detail than two words and a parenthetical comment. Can you explain how this helps solve the problem described in the original post?